# How to pass variable id from AngularJS to Django for SQL query

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a table of employees when I click a row it will get the Id of the row and pass it to django sql query.

This is my raw sql query in django

```
class GetEmployeeDetailsApi(ListAPIView):
queryset = EmployeeTb.objects.raw('SELECT * 
                                   FROM EmployeTable
                                   WHERE EmployeeId = %s', [id])
serializer_class = GetEmployeeDetailsSerializer
```

I already tried another a way to do this by fetching all records then filter it in front-end and it worked, but I do not want to do this because of security reasons, it exposes the whole table when I only need one record.

Comment: Some actual angular code in the question would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a view that extends `ModelViewSet`. This provides a full object list, plus the ability to retrieve individual objects.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

```
class EmployeeDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EmployeeTb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GetEmployeeDetailsSerializer
```

I suggest you work through the DRF tutorial, which covers basic concepts like this:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/